# Изменить права доступа к папке (Linux)

Tags: права, grub

Файлы в папке etc стали доступны только для чтения (нужно изменить настройки grub). До этого редактирование было разрешено, не знаю, почему так произошло.

Comment: Команды chmod, chown не помогают?

Comment: Что за версия Linux? Изменять рутом пробуете?

Comment: chmod и chown не помогают. Ubuntu 14.04.1. А как изменять рутом?

Comment: Внизу ответили уже

Answer (score 2):

изменять права в каталоге `/etc`, как и в любом другом каталоге, может потребоваться только в особых случаях. редактирование файла конфигурации к такому случаю, конечно, не относится.

процесс, выполняющий редактирование (точнее, чтение и запись) файла за пределами домашнего каталога пользователя (и нескольких особых каталогов `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` и т.п.), должен быть запущен с *root*-овыми привилегиями:

```
$ sudo имя.вашего.любимого.редактора /путь/к/редактируемому/файлу
```